Magento 2 : Restrict Access to Admin
I am trying to limit access to my Magento 2 admin panel via nginx using
location ~* ^/(index\.php/admin|admin) {
    00.00.00.00;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    location ~* \.php$ { try_files /dummy @proxy; }
    deny all;
}

The problem I have is, I am on a Plesk server and the site is setup with nginx in Proxy mode so all traffic is blocked to admin because I guess its not seeing my ip because of the proxy.
Does anyone have a workaround for this?

The directive 00.00.00.00; isn't something really valid in NGINX configuration.

thats my ip address just changed to zeros
